# Set indexed value by reflection gives me TargetParameterCountException

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a PolygonRenderer class containing a **Vertices** property, which is a List, holding the points of the polygon the class renders.

When I try to change a specific point in this list by reflection, I get a *System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException* on the last line of my function :

```
    public override void ApplyValue(string property, object value, int? index)
    {
        List<PropertyInfo> properties = Data.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
        PropertyInfo pi = properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == property);
        pi.SetValue(Data, value,
            index.HasValue ? new object[] { index.Value } : null);
    }
```

When I debug, I get index.Value = 3, Data is the PolygonRenderer instance and pi reflects the Vertices property, which count = 4.

Since my index is supposed to be the last item of my list, how is it possible that I get a count exception on that property ?

Thanks

Comment: Vertices is not an indexed property, that's why you are getting the exception.  Of course you didn't *actually* meant to assign the Vertices property, you need more code to use the Item property of the List.  Use pi.GetValue() first to get the List reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a PolygonRenderer class containing a Vertices property, which is a List...

So you need to execute something like this

```
Data.Vertices[index] = value
```

and what your code is trying to do is

```
Data[index] = value
```

You can use something like this instead

```
public override void ApplyValue(string property, object value, int? index)
{
    object target = Data;
    var pi = target.GetType().GetProperty(property);
    if (index.HasValue && pi.GetIndexParameters().Length != 1)
    {
        target = pi.GetValue(target, null);
        pi = target.GetType().GetProperties()
            .First(p => p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 1
            && p.GetIndexParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(int));
    }
    pi.SetValue(target, value, index.HasValue ? new object[] { index.Value } : null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It worked well :) I need to wrap my head around this to fully understand this.

Comment: Btw, `pi.GetValue(target)` compiles w/o problem - the `, null)` is not strongly needed, but doesn't hurt.

Comment: Weird, it's a no go w/o for me... VC 2015 & .net 4.0

Comment: I see. Thank you for the clarification.